# Creating an ArcMap Extension

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-desktop, visual-studio, extensions

As ArcGIS 10 doesn't really support the full COM, I am looking at creating an extension.

I am looking for samples to look through, to familiarise myself with them, but cannot find any.

Any chance someone can show some links ot some samples of creating extensions

Using VS2010 and C#

Comment: Is this for Desktop or server? which version? 10.0 or 10.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this book 2 weeks ago while browsing (again) for books covering your same question.  Definitely worth purchasing.  It's taken me a while to understand interface programming (that ArcObjects uses) but this guy explains it pretty well in Chapter 5.  Lots of sample code and examples on how to create add-in's and extensions. The book covers 10.1 as well.

Beginning ArcGIS for Desktop Development using .NET
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1118442547/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118442547)

Comment: +1 This book looks interesting, I've been waiting for something like this because my computer science courses at university focussed on pure (intensive) programming skills for people who were planning on becoming java/c++ etc developers, whereas I was thrown into the deep end of not knowing how those skills would relate to my GIS skills.

Comment: Nice to see something replace the old VBA ArcObjects book.

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating an extension that is only accessed from say desktop then consider developing an AddIn extension as these are much easier to deploy on client machines.  If you are creating an extension that makes ArcMap talk to say MS Access then a standard extension (COM) would be required but then you have to register it with the OS and deal with admin privaleges which can be a pain.

Since version 10.0 I've pretty much done all my custom development in the ESRI AddIN framework.

So for standard extensions go [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_an_application_extension/00010000001v000000/) for AddIn extensions go [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/).