# Software needed to recreate VBA forms using python for Arc 10.0

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, vba

I'm new to programming and need to convert VBA scripted tools for the 10.1 upgrade.

I need to recreate the forms and use Python scripting.

How do I do this?

I need the form to function in 10 so that the upgrade will go smooth.

A list of specific software that I will need would be so helpful.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Learning two languages (VBA and Python) and trying to understand someone else's code (as well as write your own) sounds like a big ask if you are new to programming.  I think you need to refine your question to be just the first bit you want to try and bite off.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the tool does and what kind of info the form gathers?  Python/arcpy may not be suited for what you need to do since it does not access all the available objects for ArcGIS.

Comment: If you are looking for an automated conversion tool. I would say you are never going to find it.

Answer (score 4):

If your existing VBA tool was a simple interface with drop-down menus and textboxes then you could create a Python Script and wire it into ArcToolbox to create a scripting tool that looks and behaves like any other geo-processing tool. More can be found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002q000000).

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using only Python then you don't need any additional software, however, there are some modules to aid in accessing ArcObjects. [This blog post has some helpful info.](http://www.sspinnovations.com/blog/2012/03/09/useful-scripts-non-programmer-converting-vba-scripts-python)

IMHO, if you're goal is to have a tool which is most similar to the original VBA version (in function and form) than you should be using dotNET. In which case you will need Visual Studio and the ArcObjects SDK. [This blog post has an ArcObjects VBA to C# tutorial](http://gis.qtools.com/blog/tutorials/vba-to-c-add-in/part-4-creating-new-add-in-project/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In this post [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62253/creating-an-arcmap-extension)  I recommended the [Beginning ArcGIS for Desktop Development using .NET](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118442547) book...  this is a great (non-ESRI) replacement for the Getting to Know ArcObjects book that used VBA... Something you might want to look into but if you're new to programming then this might be a little intimidating...